# Set up two external monitors on my laptop (aspire v3)

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, gpu, external-display, acer-aspire

Hi everyone i am going to buy two fullHD monitors and i would like to plug them into my laptop but i am not sure if this is possible.
To be specific i have an *Acer Aspire V3-572G-76UP* that came with:

- NVIDIA GeForce 840M
- intel i7-5500U
- HDMI, VGA ports
- as OS i am running ubuntu 16.04

and i would like to add two of [this monitor](http://www.benq.com/product/monitor/gw2470h).
HDMI and VGA cables should be enough for this task or my set up is not capable of such thing ?

Edit: this is the output i get from *xrandr*:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x 
axis    y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Check `xrandr` output to see which outputs are supported for which graphics card.

Comment: i edited with the output from xrandr, it seems two hdmi outputs are detected while i only have one port in my pc, plus i can't see the vga output, could you please be more specific when you say "for which graphics card". Thankyou in advance

Comment: Your laptop has two graphic cards, the integrated Intel one, and the NVidia one. This looks like it's the information for the integrated Intel one, and the VGA connector isn't there, so it's likely only connected to the NVidia card. Not all of the outputs shown need to be connected to anything, so possibly the HDMI connector is also connected to the NVidia card (or switched, or whatever). First step is activate both your cards (you need an `xorg.conf`, check this site), install nouveau, and check `xrandr` for the NVidia card (`--display :0.1` once it's running).

Comment: Thankyou very much, i switched to the NVidia card, this is xrandr, still cannot see VGA port.. : `Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x6384 eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 344mm x 193mm 1366x768 60.00*+ 1360x768 59.80 59.96 1024x768 60.04 60.00 960x720 60.00 928x696 60.05` ..... `DP-1 disconnected HDMI-1 disconnected HDMI-2 disconnected`

Comment: All laptops handle connectors a bit differently, so I can't tell you what's going on. Next step would be to connect an actual monitor (not necessarily the one you want to buy, any you have lying around or can borrow) to first VGA, then HDMI, and see what happens (for both cards). Does a new output show up, do you get a picture, etc. Looking at `/var/log/Xorg.log` may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If this will ever help someone : i finally bought and tried the monitors and it happened that they're working pretty well. I only got problems when switching through displays configurations : you have to connect sequentially the two monitors and then, if you want to, disable the built-in display; Otherwise you we'll be stuck with GPU problems,if that happens try to reboot without external connections, open terminal, run `rm ~/.config/monitors.xml` reboot again and then follow the procedure as explained above.